# Is it possible to initialize a vector of vectors of non-copyable objects?

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++03, noncopyable

Is it possible to initialize a vector of vectors of non-copyable objects?

```
class obj : private boost::noncopyable {
    // ...
};

vector<vector<obj> > v(10); // OK
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    v[i].resize(10); // ERROR
```

also

```
vector<vector<obj> > v(10, vector<obj>(10)); // ERROR
```

I understand **why** the above code won't compile. What I'm asking is whether there's a workaround. It seems that if `std::vector` had a member function like `resize_from_zero` that didn't need a copy constructor, then this would be doable.

(My question is about C++03, if this makes a difference)

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference - there are move semantics and `emplace_back` in C++11.

Comment: Yes it's possible in C++11 - your code would only fail to work if the type was not default constructible and not movable.

Comment: If you use primitive types instead of obj. your code could work. But based on your question. You cannot do what you want. You either choose c++11 or you do some puch_bcck s.

Comment: @BufBills You mean push_back's? Those need copy-constructors.

Comment: Just to be clear, would a C++11 approach that covers non-copyable non-movable objects be acceptable, or do you really need a C++03 approach? (I still don't think it would then work for `vector`, but a different container type might work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible; C++03 requires that elements of a `vector` be CopyConstructible and Assignable.

Rreference: C++03 [lib.containers.requirements]/3

> The type of objects stored in these components must meet the requirements of `CopyConstructible`
>   types (20.1.3), and the additional requirements of `Assignable` types.

where "these components" means `deque`, `list`, `queue`, `stack`, `vector`, `map`, `set`, `bitset`.

(There may or may not be some way to have it appear to work on a particular compiler, but that is beyond the scope of Standard C++).